# Is it possible to feed in an aggregate values to a different sub query in the select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
    select 
    max(sample) as s
    , (select result_n from result r where r.sample = s)
    , result_description
    from result
    group by result_description
```

Is it possible to feed the result of the aggregate in to the sub query as shown

Comment: Why not use two queries in a batch and store the `MAX` value in a variable?

Comment: so the reason is that this is actually written in a subroutine and then executed using a sql function.
I want the only return 1 sample and the matching result_n for the sample, for a single result description

Comment: How is what you are after different from `select * from result where sample in ( select max(sample) as s from result group by result_description )`   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a80f17/4

Comment: you are right, I am an idiot, thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select max(r.sample) as s,
       (select r2.result_n
        from result r2
        where r2.sample = max(r.sample)
       ),
       r.result_description
from result r
group by r.result_description
```